# how i can pass dynamically generate fields value to php on same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

1. I'm dynamically generating on button with values.
2. I have used array as name also inside the button field but unable to receive value of it.
3. I need to get each of button generated value on same page using php after submitting the form.
   Here is my code.

```js
$('#left_indicator').on('change', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    /* Act on the event */
    if ($(this).val()=='sma') {
      $("#left_period_guider").html('(period,offset)');
    }else if ($(this).val()=='ema') {
      $("#left_period_guider").html('(close,period,offset)');
    }
    
  });
  $('#right_indicator').on('change', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    /* Act on the event */
    if ($(this).val()=='sma') {
      $("#right_period_guider").html('(period,offset)');
    }else if ($(this).val()=='ema') {
      $("#right_period_guider").html('(close,period,offset)');
    }
    
  });
/*  -----------------------------------*/
 var data='';
var btnid=0;
function generateBtn(data){
    btnid++;
    var btns='<button type="button" id="generated'+btnid+'" name="generated[]'+btnid+'" value="" data-id="'+btnid+'">'+data+'</button><button type="button" id="removethis" class="removethis" data-id="'+btnid+'">removethis</button>';
    $('#container').append(btns);
}
function check_inputs() {
    var i=0;
    //validation to check for empty inputs
    //Same loop used to generate valid Button' Data
    
    data='';
    //we reset Data
    $('.chk').each(function(){
        
        if( $(this).val() === "" ){
          $(this).css({'border-color':'red','border-size':'3px'}); 
        } else{
            $(this).css({'border-color':'green','border-size':'3px'});
            if($(this).is('input')){
                data+='('+$(this).val()+')';
            } else {
                data+=' '+$(this).val();
            }
            
            i++;
        }
    });
    if(i==$('.chk').length){
    //We gernerate the button
    generateBtn(data);
    } else{
        return;
    }
}

//Dynamically generated buttons are non-Dom, so we base selction on the parent container
//Data-id attribute is used to match targeted buttons
$("#container").on('click','.removethis', function() {
        $('button[data-id='+$(this).data('id')+']').remove();
});    
$("#generateButton").on('click', function() {  
    //Because we can remove buttons
    //We count generated buttons before generating more than 5
    if($("[id^=generated]").length<10){
    check_inputs();
    }
});
```

```html
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title>Demo</title>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
 <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div id="container">
  <select name="left_indicator" id="left_indicator" class="chk">
      <option value="">select</option>
      <option value="sma">sma</option>
      <option value="ema">ema</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="left_PeriodAndOffset" id="left_PeriodAndOffset" placeholder="e.g (10.2)" class="chk">
    <div id="left_period_guider"></div>
    <select name="comparator" id="comparator" class="chk">
      <option value="">select</option>
      <option value="=">=</option>
      <option value="<"><</option>
    </select>


    <select name="right_indicator" id="right_indicator" class="chk">
      <option value="">select</option>
      <option value="sma">sma</option>
      <option value="ema">ema</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="right_PeriodAndOffset" id="right_PeriodAndOffset" placeholder="e.g (10.2)" class="chk">
    <div id="right_period_guider"></div>

    <button type="button" id="generateButton" name="generateButton">click to generate button upto 5 with remove button</button>
    <hr>
</div>
<button type="submit">click me</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see,
I'm selecting value from dropdown and generating button field with value by clicking on generate button.
I just need generated button values on same page after submitting a form using php.

Comment: At first sight It seems your buttons have empty value attribute (value=""). Have you tried adding some value to it, for example value="button'+btnid+'_value" ?

Comment: As pointed out, your generated buttons have no `value`s - you are using the `data` only as a text on the button.  As a side note, you will probably get a better response if you can edit your question down to a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - simplify it down to just the code necessary to reproduce the problem.